# Reading File Into Struct Pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

My file format is :
"`name#totalMoney#ratio#luckyNumber"`
I,m trying to read that into a dynamic struct pointer.(i want to use it like array)
I want to assign all the lines in the file to the struct array by assigning each line to an element of the struct array.My problem is when i compile this code only the first line of the file is read into struct array and nothing else.Thank for your helps..

```
#include"Person.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<math.h>
#define NAMSZ 50//LENGTH FOR NAME BUFFER


    void test_1(){
       People *tmp=NULL;
       int lengtPerson=pFileLength();//it returns number of line in the file
       tmp=allocate_struct_array(&tmp,lengtPerson);
       readPerson(&tmp);
      }
       
    void main(){    
      test_1();    
    }
    #include"Person.h"//it contains declaration of the functions below and
/*typedef struct P{
     char *name;
     double totalMoney;
     double ratio;
     double luckyNumber;
}   People; */
    People *allocate_struct_array(People **parr,int total_line){
        return *parr = malloc (total_line * sizeof **parr);
    }
    int readPerson(People **parr){
         char c;
        int MAXC=500;//max length of a line in the file
        char buf[MAXC];    
                    /* temporary array to hold each line */
        int count = 0, 
            nparr = 0,
           count_lines = 0;
        
        FILE *fileptr = fopen ("Kisiler.txt", "r");
        
        if (!fileptr) {     /* always validate file open for reading */
            perror ("fopen-fileptr");
            
        }
       
        while (nparr <= count_lines && fgets (buf, MAXC, fileptr)) {
            char name[NAMSZ];       //temporary array for name 
            size_t len;             // length of name
          
            if (sscanf (buf, "%[^#]#%lf#%lf#%lf",name, &(parr[nparr]->totalMoney),
                        &(parr[nparr]->ratio),&(parr[nparr]->luckyNumber)) != 4) {
                fputs ("error: invalid line format.\n", stderr);
                continue;
            }
            len = strlen (name);    // get length of name 
            
             parr[nparr]->name = malloc (len + 1);        // allocate for name  
            if (!parr[nparr]->name) {                    // validate allocation 
                perror ("malloc-parr[nparr].name");
                break;
            }
            memcpy (parr[nparr]->name, &name, len + 1);
            
            nparr += 1;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nparr; i++) {
            printf ("  %-20s %8lf %5lf %5lf\n", 
                    parr[i]->name,parr[i]->totalMoney,parr[i]->ratio,parr[i]->luckyNumber);
            //free (parr[i].name);            /* free strings when done */
        }
        //free (parr);   
        return count_lines;
    
       fclose(fileptr);
    
    
    }
```

Comment: This code is both *not* a proper [mcve] *and* harboring a litany of bugs. We *may* be able to help with the latter, but first we need the former.

Comment: What should i edit ,,or add

Comment: It is explained in the link I already showed. Look at what you posted. Look **only** at what you posted and *nothing* else. If we copy, paste, compile, link, and run that code, and only that code, can we reproduce your problem? No: because there are a multitude of things in that code that are *not* resolved. We don't know what a `Person` is. We don't know what `NAMEZ`, or `MAXC` are. We don't know what `pFileLength()` does., or have example data from your input file.  Summary: we do not have a proper [mcve], and without one, there is very little chance we can do anything short of guessing.

Comment: @WhozCraig i guess we are clear now ,i editted the question as you said,if you can help me ill be  appreciated.

Comment: Somehow, we're *not* clear. It *still* isn't a proper [mcve], but I may be able to work with it. We also need a data file with at least as much data as required to reproduce your issue, posted *in your question* as a separate source text. And we still don't have `pFileLength()` Please stop thinking we can see the code on *your* screen. All we have is what you post here. Please add the sample data, sufficient to reproduce your issue, assuming I can get this code to actually compile.

Comment: I suspect [this](https://godbolt.org/z/oode71qE4) is what you're actually trying to do, or at least similar to it (without having to scan the input file multiple times during the read).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes!This is exactly what i was trying to do thank you so much.I have only one question left.In main couldnt we use int i as a loop condition as we use in arrays.İt looks like kinda foreach to me  .